# RichFaces 4.5 commandLink execute form with ID

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces, execute, commandlink

I wonder if I can use the execute attribute of the `a4j:commandLink` component to submit a form using the form id. Here is my code:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
     // fields and values and stuff.....

</h:form>

<a4j:region>
    <a4j:commandLink execute="myForm" id="myLink" value="Click Here" render="someComponent" actionListener="#{myBean.myAction}"/>
</a4j:region>
```

If this is not doable, please suggest me some other way to achieve this.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier (and faster) to try it and see if it works?

Comment: @Makhiel And you thought that I didn't try it? c'mon.... I wouldn't waste my time asking in here... anyways I tried and it is not working !!

Comment: Well sorry but there's nothing in your post to suggest you tried. What version of RichFaces do you use? It works fine with 4.5.3.

Comment: @Makhiel JSF 2.2 and RichFaces 4.5.0...... It works only if you try submitting in the same form.. I need to submit my form, from outside of it, like in my code, that execute="myForm" is not working.

Comment: Ok, doesn't work with MyFaces, why do you need to have the button outside of the form?